# Single Select Statement as Multiple Parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a Function that allows 2 parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunction( 'Value1', 'Value2' )
```

I need to pass the parameters by using a sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunction
( 
    ( SELECT Column1 FROM MyTable WHERE Rec = 1 ), 
    ( SELECT Column2 FROM MyTable WHERE Rec = 1 ) 
)
```

Since the 2 Select Statements are referencing the same table, I was wondering if it's possible to pass the values through a single select statement something to this effect:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunction( ( SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM MyTable WHERE Rec = 1 ) )
```

Is something like that even possible?  It has to remain as a single statement as above, using Variables are unfortunately not possible otherwise I could easily do this:

```
DECLARE @Var1 nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @Var2 nvarchar(20)
SELECT @Var1 = Column1, @Var2 = Column2 FROM MyTable WHERE Rec = 1
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunction( @Var1, @Var2 )
```

The Script is inputted into a parsing engine for a web application but it only supports a basic SELECT function as the script gets ripped apart and then put back together to prevent SQL Injection Attacks so we're very limited in what we're able to do.  The First and Second scripts above work perfectly, I just wanted to see if there was a way to get the Third script to work optimize the script.

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT r.* --TODO - Pick columns
FROM
   MyTable t
     CROSS APPLY dbo.MyFunction(t.Column1,t.Column2) as r
WHERE
   t.Rec = 1
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply, I was rushed to meetings for two days straight.  This is such an awesome answer, I absolutely love it.  While I haven't yet had chance to study it in detail or study the documentation, I will be doing so tonight, I just wanted to first stop and say thank you :)

Comment: Hi Damien, I just managed to get time this weekend to properly study the [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) functionality and apply it to my scenario, I managed to reduce the end result from 7 individual SQL Statements into just 1, awesome stuff.  Thanks again!